# Close Find Bar without focus with Esc in Firefox

Tags: firefox, hotkeys, user-interface

Right now there are two ways to close the Find Bar in Firefox: click the "x" button or set the focus to the Find Bar text input and press Esc. I'm looking for a way to close Find Bar with Esc key when it's not focused

Comment: and what if the webpage is also listening to the `Esc` key?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could press ctrl+F to get focus, but maybe you meant programmatically.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I'd like to close it only with Esc, not setting focus beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Using autohotkey...

```
#IfWinActive,  ahk_class MozillaWindowClass  ;Mozilla Firefox

esc::   ; close firefox find box

sendInput, ^f      ; ff hotkey to open and/or set focus to 

find bar

sleep, 100         ; time to react

sendInput, {esc}   ; ff hotkey to close find (if find has focus)

return             

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150566)

Comment: always pressing Ctrl+F like this isn't a good solution at all. There are lots of web pages that need to listen to the Esc key, for example the new event dialog in google calendar, or the new email in outlook